# Keeping number format when changing number to string

Tags: spss

I occasionally need to change numbers into strings, while keeping a nice number format (e.g. in order to place them into sentences built through syntax).
It's easy enough to keep the decimals part of the format, for example:

```
string MyTextN (a10).
compute MyTextN=string(MyNumericN, f10.2).
```

so a number like **12345.6789** is saved as this text: **"  12345.68"**.
What I'm missing is the 1000's separator. I would like the text to be: **"  12,345.68"**.
Right now I'm doing some text manipulations to get this (generally - looping through the digits and inserting commas before the fourth and seventh one),
but i'm wondering if there's a built it function i'm not aware of, or if anyone can suggest a shortcut?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the transformation system and backend generally do not know about the digit-grouping setting, so the string function ignores it (which is probably what you want most of the time).

You can use Python for this, e.g.,

```
'{:,}'.format(123456789)
```

'123,456,789'

The SPSSINC TRANS command could be used to do this, though it might be overkill.

Here is an example, where x is the variable to be converted to a string.

```
begin program.  
def strWSeparators(x):
    if x is not None:  
        return '{:,}'.format(x)
    else:
        return None
end program.

spssinc trans result=y type=15
/formula "strWSeparators(x)".
```

The result is a 15-byte string variable, y,